# FB chatbot replies to me only

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, rasa

I created chatbot in Rasa and then integrated it to FB messenger.
Everything has been setup properly however there is a problem,only I can test it. When I text bot it replies me,but if my friend tries to do same thing,nothing happens.
I tried adding my friends to admin, developer or testers roles but they didn't receive the request to accept and hence when they talk to bot, bot is not replying still.

Can anyone please help by guiding me to what is missing.

Comment: _“but they didn't receive the request”_ - they are probably not registered as developers then. (I think you get asked the first time you visit https://developers.facebook.com/, or sth. - can’t remember exactly, it’s been a while.) And for your bot to work for everyone, you will have to submit your app for review.

Answer (score 1):

So i found a solution for one of the problem where i had added few friends as testers but they were not receiving any request on their facebook notification.

Solution -> It's quite weird, people (testers) were getting notifications but that notifications can be seen only when they had opened their facebook account from desktop or laptop (and not mobile). It took me quite while to know about this fact. Another things is, facebook asks them to register themselves as developers before accepting the request. Once they register themselves on developers for facebook website, they can chat with your chatbot.

Comment: Such a pain to get business users to test the bots :) Had to make a video and send them

Answer (score 1):

your friends will need to create a developer account(they have to navigate to https://developers.facebook.com and create the account there) and of course, you have to invite them as testers of your app. they will then need to accept the invite.

my non-techie friends had a hard time navigating the account creation process.